# How to Check if service available in given location or not Google Map API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

i'm working in taxi booking app, for this i'm also displaying the google map for searched `pickup location` and `drop location`, and there is a `condition` in booking, that is we are providing our service inside `I-285 Atlanta, GA, USA` Perimeter and 100 miles outside of this perimeter. when searched this address in google, it shows a polygon with red color. but i did not find any help in google for checking if users destination lies inside this perimeter or outside this perimeter.

Any hints would be great.

[Check the map here, i want this area cordinates, i want to know if searched location lies inside this area or outside this area](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1xCAYRGl-LPxue2pgFLYESKRyoaQ&hl=en_US&ll=33.63663200000001%2C-84.49224500000003&z=10)

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html) or [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html)?

Comment: search for this location `I-285, Atlanta, GA, USA` in map you can see the boundary area with `285` numbered . i want that areas cordinates

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and I'm just adding full code, someone may need it.

Setup two input box for autocomplete address, search for location, and script will search for location you selected lies inside the polygon or not. but polygon is not visible to user. Because I do not want that, but if you want to display, please remove comment from this line `polygon.setMap(map)`. Script will show the route and duration.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="source">
<input type="text" id="destination">
<div id="divAlertError"></div>

<div id="map"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=us&key=YOUR_MAP_API_KEY" aysnc defer></script>
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeControl: false,

      center: {lat: 33.63663200000001, lng: -84.49224500000003},
      zoom: 10
    });

    new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
  }

   /**
    * @constructor autocomplete
   */
  function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {

    this.map = map;
    this.originPlaceId = null;
    this.destinationPlaceId = null;
    this.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
    //this.polygon='';
    var originInput = document.getElementById('source');
    var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination');
    //var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    //var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); //Added on 27/09/2016
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


    var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
    var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});

     // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
      var atlantaArea = [
          {lat: 33.636632 , lng: -84.492245},
          {lat: 33.656424 , lng: -84.497566},
          {lat: 33.690281 , lng: -84.500055},
          {lat: 33.722983 , lng: -84.50263},
          {lat: 33.753532 , lng: -84.495506},
          {lat: 33.764842 , lng: -84.493361},
          {lat: 33.786852 , lng: -84.493146},
          {lat: 33.799477 , lng: -84.488468},
          {lat: 33.825221 , lng: -84.489541},
          {lat: 33.843117 , lng: -84.487481},
          {lat: 33.86418 , lng: -84.479628},
          {lat: 33.884418 , lng: -84.470015},
          {lat: 33.890296 , lng: -84.460917},
          {lat: 33.906397 , lng: -84.431992},
          {lat: 33.915942 , lng: -84.406672},
          {lat: 33.912167 , lng: -84.379163},
          {lat: 33.910208 , lng: -84.361782},
          {lat: 33.912024 , lng: -84.357147},
          {lat: 33.913769 , lng: -84.352083},
          {lat: 33.918007 , lng: -84.338307},
          {lat: 33.920322 , lng: -84.30522},
          {lat: 33.912986 , lng: -84.286294},
          {lat: 33.902906 , lng: -84.274063},
          {lat: 33.891757 , lng: -84.2593},
          {lat: 33.885487 , lng: -84.251575},
          {lat: 33.851261 , lng: -84.246597},
          {lat: 33.846431 , lng: -84.247198},
          {lat: 33.827218 , lng: -84.252477},
          {lat: 33.816023 , lng: -84.251447},
          {lat: 33.802936 , lng: -84.250138},
          {lat: 33.778184 , lng: -84.241297},
          {lat: 33.764753 , lng: -84.232392},
          {lat: 33.752604 , lng: -84.231899},
          {lat: 33.737171 , lng: -84.230762},
          {lat: 33.714702 , lng: -84.240954},
          {lat: 33.698994 , lng: -84.266081},
          {lat: 33.683997 , lng: -84.310048},
          {lat: 33.672854 , lng: -84.328415},
          {lat: 33.668015 , lng: -84.340324},
          {lat: 33.65203 , lng: -84.367125},
          {lat: 33.633023 , lng: -84.400975},
          {lat: 33.624894 , lng: -84.422486},
          {lat: 33.617139 , lng: -84.438515},
          {lat: 33.620516 , lng: -84.460616},
          {lat: 33.619319 , lng: -84.483039},
          {lat: 33.623143 , lng: -84.488318}
      ];

      // Construct the polygon.
      var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: atlantaArea,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });
      //polygon.setMap(map);  
      this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);       

    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(this.map,infowindow,originAutocomplete, 'ORIG',polygon);
    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(this.map,infowindow,destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST',polygon);

  }


  /*AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.drawPolygon = function(map)
  {

  }*/


  /*place changed listner*/
  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(map,infowindow,autocomplete, mode,polygon) {
    var me = this;
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.place_id) {
        window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
        return;
      }
      var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(me.bounds.getSouthWest(), me.bounds.getNorthEast());

      if (!place.geometry) {
        me.geocodeAddress(place.name,polygon);          
        //window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        //return;
      };          

      if (mode === 'ORIG') {
        me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
      } else {
        me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
      }
      me.route(map,infowindow);


    });/*listner*/

  };

   AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.geocodeAddress = function(addr,polygon) {
      var me = this;
      me.geocoder.geocode({'address': addr}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          var newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(me.bounds.getSouthWest(), me.bounds.getNorthEast());
          //console.log(results);
          //newBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
          //map.fitBounds(newBounds);
          if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(results[0].geometry.location, polygon)){
          jQuery('#divAlertError').text('The area contains the address');  
          } else {
          jQuery('#divAlertError').text('The address is outside of the area.');  
          };
        } else {
        jQuery('#divAlertError').text('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });
    };

  /*Route*/
  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function(map,infowindow) {
    if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
      return;
    }
    var me = this;

    this.directionsService.route({
      origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
      destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
      travelMode: this.travelMode
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        console.log(response);
        me.computeTotals(map,response,infowindow);
        //console.log(infowindow);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  };

  /*Find Distance and Duration*/
  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.computeTotals = function(map,result,infowindow) {
      var me = this;          

      var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      service.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins: [result.request.origin],
          destinations: [result.request.destination],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
      }, function (response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
            console.log(response);
              var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
              //convert meters in km then Miles
              var meter = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
              var distanceInMiles = (Number(meter)*0.00062137).toFixed(2);
              var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;

             infowindow.setContent('<i style="color:blue;" class="fa fa-car fa-2x"></i><center><b>'+distance+'( '+distanceInMiles+' miles) '+'<br>'+duration+'</b></center>');
             infowindow.setPosition(map.getCenter());
             infowindow.open(map);

          } else {
              alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
          }
      });
    }
```